# Having trouble connecting to mlab using node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

I'm trying to connect to mlab using node with little success. I use this line to connect to my db

`mongoose.connect(mymlabDBurl, { useMongoClient: true });`

I have then tried to test that it works by hitting my API end points. I know this works because the first `console.log` below works. However when I try and save to my database I never hit the next two `console.log`s. How can I test for why this connection to the db is failing?

```
exports.add_name = function (req, res) {
    const newName = new Name(req.body);
    console.log(newName); //this prints
    newName.save(function (err, name) {
        console.log(name); //this doesnt print
        console.log(err); //this also doesnt print
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(name);
    });
};
```

Comment: `mongoose.connect(mymlabDBurl, { useMongoClient: true })` requires a callback or promise resolution in modern releases, which is why you would have received the deprecation message without `useMongoClient` in the first place. The point is that your sever startup ( ie `listen()` ) needs to happen "inside" that callback or promise resolve. If you don't do that, everything hangs awaiting the connection call to actually be made.

Comment: Hey @NeilLunn, thanks for your input. I'm pretty new to node. I tried changing the connect to `mongoose.connect(configDB.url, (err, db) => {
    console.log(err);
});` and I still get the error `{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [ds141464.mlab.com:41464] on first connect [MongoError: connection 0 to ds141464.mlab.com:41464 timed out]`. Would you mind explaining a bit more in detail about how my server startup should be? It seems to still be hanging.

Comment: That's a different problem. Now it's actually trying to establish the connection but cannot since the host is unreachable from the location your app is running. Either that or the port is incorrect/blocked. You need to check networking settings on your application environment. Note you still really "should use" the `{ useMongoClient: true }` option since the deprecation warning means that future releases will generally require it ( or default that way ).

Comment: I changed that line of code to `mongoose.connect(configDB.url, { useMongoClient: true }, (err, db) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    app.listen(port);
    console.log('running on: ' + port);
});` and I still get the same error put wrapped inside of a promise warning. Could you give me some advice on how to debug this? I'm at a total loss and quite frustrated. Thanks

Comment: `app.listen` does not even start up my server in this code though. ]

Comment: the `console.log(err)` does not even get called. I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Well `function (req, res)` tells me that you are likely using express, so it actually does start up your server even if your impression is that it does not. As I pointed out, with the correction to the connection method your "new issue" is actually networking related. To "debug" you should ensure the server ( database ) is actually running and can be reached from where you are attempting to run the code. Your best approach when "new to this" is to attempt to run locally first, and then work out the remote connection as a separate process.

Comment: You're right, I am using express. I started off connecting to local with `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Namedb'); 
` which worked fine. It seems to never receive a response from mlab because the callback is never invoked.

Comment: You need to understand that you have a "nework communication issue", and that is not something we can correct in your code or really assist you with debugging. If you are unsure of the general code usage, then you can post a [Minimal and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), being a very simple express set up, a single model and route to return data. We can then post corrections to that code. However that does not resolve `failed to connect to server` as that is something you can only resolve yourself as you have been pointed to.